# Boundedness of a function of a exponential random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

If $X$ is an exponential random variable with mean 1 and let $f(x)$ be a function such that the $k^{th}$ derivative of the function is bounded. Then can I say that the expectation $\mathbb E[f(X)]$ is bounded?

My intuition is that this is true. Since the $k^{th}$ derivative is bounded I think we can bound the function by some polynomial and since the moments of the exponential are bounded, that will imply $\mathbb E[f(X)]$ is bounded. Is this correct?

Comment: I can't remember the details very well but the nth derivative of the mgf evaluated at zero gives you the nth moment ( see the link ) so I think you can use that to prove what you're trying to prove. https://www.statlect.com/fundamentals-of-probability/cumulant-generating-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's correct. Applying the fundamental theorem of calculus, we get that $f$ is bounded by a polynomial of degree $k$, say $p_k(x)$. Since $E(X^k) < \infty$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ for an exponentially distributed random variable $X$, it follows that $E(f(X)) \leq E(p_k(X)) < \infty$.